# Can $\mathbb{S}^2$ wind around $\mathbb{S}^2$ twice, just like you would wind $\mathbb{S}^1$ around $\mathbb{S}^1$ $n$ times

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**NOTE:** This question is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033601) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319264). These questions are answered.

I know this topic is about algebraic topology, but my knowledge there is rather weak.
I essentially want to know if there exists a continuous function $\varphi:\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$ such that $(\forall x\in\mathbb{S}^2)|\varphi^{-1}(x)|=2$?

**Background thinking:**
If we replaced $\mathbb{S}^2$ with $\mathbb{S}^1$ and understood $\mathbb{S}^1$ as $R=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|1=|z|\}$ then $x\mapsto x^2$ would satisfy my condition. I wanted to do it with $\mathbb{S}^2$ too but it seemed that some point would be covered infinitely many times (here I had layering into longitutes in mind). Then I wanted to avoid that infinity and I reduced the problem to inverting $R$ to itself but with reversed orientation with bounded covering, or more precisely a function $f:\mathbb{S}^1\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(\mathbb{S}^1\times\{0\})=R$, $f(\mathbb{S}^1\times\{1\})=R$ but reversed and $|f^{-1}(x)|\le2$ for every $x$. I found it and induced a related $\varphi$ but then I got two points which I covered only once. Then I remembered that I could simply twist the sphere just like $\mathbb{S}^1$ at all latitudes and leave the poles in place and I would have the exact same situation: Every point is covered twice except the poles which are covered only once. This made me thinking that I will always have such 2 points that I covered only once, either that or two infinitely covered points as with longitudes. How would I even go about proving it?

**EDIT:** Comments gave some help towards **formalizing** my examples I gave in the discussion, so here is the clear definition of those 2 maps, after we identified $\mathbb{S}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}P^1$:

The longitudal one: $z\mapsto\frac{z}{|z|(1-|z|)}$; it covers the $\infty$ infinitely many times.

The latitudal one: $z\mapsto z^2$; it covers $0$ and $\infty$ only once.

**EDIT 2:** I have **progressed** a tiny little bit: If $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, $X$ being compact and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection then $f$ is a homeomorphism.
Now I thought I could find some meaningful subset of $\mathbb{S}^2$ for which $\varphi$ restricted to it has this property, but I failed...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141205/discussion-on-question-by-donaastor-can-mathbbs2-wind-around-mathbbs2).

Comment: I repost the duplicate [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319264/does-there-exist-a-continuous-2-to-1-function-from-the-sphere-to-itself) for ease of everyone's reference

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [MO post linked in the question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319264/does-there-exist-a-continuous-2-to-1-function-from-the-sphere-to-itself), there is no such map. The key step is to construct out of $\varphi$ a continuous involution of $S^2$, which must be conjugate in the homeomorphism group to either a reflection or a rotation by $\pi$.